# Extend trait with private constructor parameter

Tags: scala, traits

In Scala, how can I extend a trait in a class with **private** constructor parameter that is defined in the trait?

```
trait Parent {
  protected def name: String
  require(name != "", "wooo problem!")
}

class Child(private val name: String) extends Parent {
  println("name is " + name)
}
```

The above class gives an error:

> class Child needs to be abstract, since method name in trait Parent of type ⇒ String is not defined.

Of-course I can:

1. make the `Child` class abstract,
2. define it without using the private in the constructor like `class Child(val name: String)`.
3. make the Parent an `abstract class` instead of a trait

But with the above implementation, is there no way I can have a **private** constructor parameter while extending a trait? Note that I want the variable to be private so that I should not be able to do `childInstance.name`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Why do you need a constructor with a private variable? Can't you just define the private variable in the class and have an empty constructor?

Comment: Since this class is being extended by several children, I don't want to repeat the code. I think I found a way though. If I make the variable in the trait `protected` and change the child constructor to `Child(name: String)`, I cannot access the variable outside. This is good enough for me!

Comment: Why don't you just define `class Child{ private val name = "" }` ?

Comment: That is because I have some method signatures in the trait that I want all the children to define. So a trait makes more sense in my opinion! Let me know if I am wrong. Sorry I should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  trait Parent {
    protected def name: String
    require(name != "", "wooo problem!")
  }

  class Child(override protected val name: String) extends Parent {
    val publicVar = "Hello World"
    println("name is " + name)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val child = new Child("John Doe")
    println(child.publicVar)
    println(child.name) // Does not compile
  }
```

You will not be able to access to child.name

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I need the variable to be **private**. So no, I don't want to use `override`.

Comment: I change both to be protected. When I changed child to private it is not working any more.
Error message:
class Child needs to be abstract, since method name in trait Parent of type => String is not defined

Comment: I updated the code again. I think that the example does what you want:

println(child.name) // Does not compile

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found a way as I mentioned in my comment below the question. Similar to what you are doing, except I don't need to use `override protected val` in the child constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an abstract method in a trait, then all the derived classes need to have the same (or more permissive) modifier (in your case at least protected) for the abstract methods.

```
trait Parent {
  protected def name: String
  require(name != "", "wooo problem!")
}

class Child(private val privateName: String) extends Parent {
  override protected def name: String = privateName
  println("name is " + name)
}
```

You can keep your constructor private, but you need to define the `override protected def name: String` and make use of the private value of your constructor.